# 2D RANSAC linear regression with PCL

Tags: point-cloud-library, ransac

I didn't find how to use pcl to do a 2D RANSAC linear regression. I guess that some method is not implemented. When I add `pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXY> segmentation`, the code compiles but I get a linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: lib.so: undefined reference to `pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXY>::segment(pcl::PointIndices&, pcl::ModelCoefficients&)'
/usr/bin/ld: lib.so: undefined reference to `pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXY>::initSAC(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: lib.so: undefined reference to `pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXY>::initSACModel(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My workaround is to use `pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ> segmentation` and setting z=0 but that's an extra step to transform the points from 2D to 3D.